# How do I get Nokogiri to add the right XML encoding?

Tags: ruby, xml, encoding, nokogiri

I have created a xml doc with Nokogiri: `Nokogiri::XML::Document`

The header of my file is `<?xml version="1.0"?>` but I'd expect to have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. Is there any options I could use so the encoding appears ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Are you using Nokogiri [XML Builder](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html)? You can pass an encoding option to the new() method:

> new(options = {})
>
> Create a new Builder object. options
>   are sent to the top level Document
>   that is being built.
>
> Building a document with a particular encoding for example:

```
  Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
    ...
  end
```

Also [this page](http://nokogiri.org/) says you can do the following (when not using Builder):

```
doc = Nokogiri.XML('<foo><bar /><foo>', nil, 'EUC-JP')
```

Presumably you could change 'EUC-JP' to 'UTF-8'.

Comment: It's funny that this has been one of my most highly upvoted answers. I have never used Nokogiri or Ruby, just XML and google search.

Answer (score 5):

When parsing the doc you can set the encoding like this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(xml_input, nil, "UTF-8")
```

For me that returns 
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: in fact, I do not parse an existing file but create a new one using Nokogiri::XML::Document.new

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using `Nokogiri::XML::Builder` but rather creating a document object directly, you can just set the encoding with [`Document#encoding=`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#encoding=-instance_method):

```rb
doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.new
# => #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x1180 name="document">
puts doc.to_s
# <?xml version="1.0"?>
doc.encoding = 'UTF-8'
puts doc.to_s
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```